# "Sequence contains more than one matching element" when calling Stored Procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, stored-procedures

I'm trying to show a list on my page using MyList:

```
  public List<ResponseType> MyList(int param1, DateTime Date)
        {
            return db.spMyStoredProcedure(param1, param2).ExecuteTypedList<ResponseType>();
        }
```

Which calls this stored procedure:

```
    public StoredProcedure spMyStoredProcedure(int param1,DateTime Date){
        StoredProcedure sp=new StoredProcedure("spMyStoredProcedure",this.Provider);
        sp.Command.AddParameter("param1",LeadStatusID,DbType.Int32);
        sp.Command.AddParameter("Date",Date,DbType.DateTime);
        return sp;
    }
```

Using this class:

```
public class ResponseType
    {
        public string 1 { get; set; }
        public bool2 { get; set; }
        public DateTime 3 { get; set; }
...etc.
        }
```

ResponseType inherits another class, which in turn inherits another class.

Does the error message "Sequence contains more than one matching element" mean that there are multiple declarations for ResponseType (or the classes it inherits)? I only seem to have one of each declared, which is also where Visual Studio leads me to when I click "Go to Declaration".

I can execute the Stored Procedure fine in SQL Server with the same parameters I'm passing in, so I'm unsure why the list if failing to display.

Comment: What does the stored procedure return when you run it in SQL server?

Comment: That error occurs using linq `SingleOrDefault` and the result contains more than one matching element. I don't know anything about SubSonic and `ExecuteTypedList` to know if this might be the problem

Comment: What framework are you using? What's the stack trace of your exception? Is it occurring in `ExecuteTypedList`?

Comment: Are you using Single Method?

Comment: @DGibbs The Stored Procedure returns a list in the expected format.



Stephen I understand that using SingleOrDefault wouldn't work with a list, but I'm not using that. I'm using .NET framework 4.

RobH Yes the Error mentioned is of type InvalidOperationException, and occurs on the line "return db.spMyStoredProcedure" line. 
Subsonic ExecuteTypedList is defined as "public List<T> ExecuteTypedList<T>() where T : new();"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry everyone, my problem was that I had defined a variable in ResponseType, and then again in a class it inherited.

Obviously there was no way for you to know that, as I hadn't included the inherited class. 
Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that you are using [`SingleOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/bb342451(v=vs.110).aspx) or `Single` methods elsewhere. They succeed only when the collections contains  0 or 1 element. Why don't you try with `FirstOrDefault` which take always the first element (or `defualt(type)`)?

Look at possible exception for SingleOrDefault:

1. `ArgumentNullException` --> source is null
2. `InvalidOperationException` --> **The input sequence contains more than one element**

Another possibility would be a `First()` call in your `HttpPost` method. Something like

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Test(int Id)
{
        var query = myDb.Responses
              .Where(y => y.Id==Id).First();     

    return Json(new { Test= query.Name}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

and if your Id doesn't exist that error can occur.

Comment: That would explain it, but I don't believe I am using single or SingleOrDefault anywhere.

I call MyList in the controller using HttpPost ActionResult, which in turn gets called from a Javascript ajax post.

Comment: Are you using `.First()` elsewhere?